# A list of IP addresses stored within the array, with only the first Octets, I need to display a specific message to anyone who falls w/ in Range

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ip

Second time posting on here so bear with me.

I have an array variable that contains a list of IP addresses with the first 3 Octets.

```
internal = '123.156.189','122.198.44','120.120.120','111.156.40'
```

I grab the user's IP using an API from apify.org, store it into a variable of IP, and manually compare that specific IP to a string

If I have the full ip IP address within the array. I could use `.includes` to see if there was a match (credit to another user on this forum).

```
  const FullIP = ['123.156.189.120','122.198.44.10','120.120.120.35','111.156.40.10']

  for( let i = 0; i<FullIP.length; i++) {
    if (FullIP.includes(ip)) {
      document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "block"
      
    } else
      document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none"
  }
```

Now I have to use the first three octets only to show the same message, but `.includes()` doesn't work. I have tried using`.find()` and `prototype.some()` but it doesn't seem to work either.

What can i do to call on the new array `internal = '123.156.189','122.198.44','120.120.120','111.156.40'` and still display the message?

Comment: I don't understand the loop. It repeats the same code block unrelated to the loop variable. Can you show your approach with `some`?

Comment: const Internal= ['123.156.189','122.198.44','120.120.120','111.156.40']

  for( let i = 0; i<Internal.length; i++) {
    if (ip.some(Internal[i])) {
      document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "block"
      
    } else
      document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none"
  }

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. It's not readable. Edit your question and add it there.